# Best way to support 540X960 and 480X800 -- both hdpi?

Tags: android

I have 3 phones -- a Motorola ATRIX 2 mb865, a Motorola DROID X, and a HTC Droid Incredible 2 ADR6350. The Motorola ATRIX 2 is Android 2.3.5, the HTC is Android 2.3.4, and the Motorola DROID X is Android 2.3. I can't get the app to display correctly on all three screens.

Since they are all high density--HDPI, creating a drawable-hdpi directory didn't seem to do any good. With the same artwork (480x800), the fields fits ok on the Motorola DROID X and on HTC but is too small on the Motorola Atrix 2. So I figured it was a screen size problem, but I've been trying a lot of different recommendations (drawable-sw540dp, drawable-sw330dp,drawable-h500dp, layout-sw540dp, or a number of others) but still does not work. I cant figure it out how to fit perfectly in all three devices.

I was trying to do what this guys were saying but with no success.
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2784/best-way-to-support-540x960-and-480x800-both-hdpi

If you guys have some suggestions I'd appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Show us some of your layout and what you're trying to display correctly. Some screenshots of what's wrong would be nice! We need more info to help you!

Comment: I can't show any screenshot because the project is under development, but basically the problem is I have images (480x800) that i used on the drawable-hdpi and it seemed to work just fine, but when I tried the app on the Atrix 2, which screen size is 540x960, the images displayed too small. What can I do to make it fit on this device? should I recreate the images for its device? If so how can I define the folder structure?

Comment: stretch the images..?

Comment: how can I stretch the images?

Comment: how are you trying to display the drawables? as a background of imageview/layout or, as src of an imageview?

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered if I answered your question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me. I guess Im gonna have to do it programmatically.

This might help someone else in the future.Here's the link:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2784/best-way-to-support-540x960-and-480x800-both-hdpi

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to handle this is by using a 9patch, rather than a bitmap.

The 9patch will "fill" to any size with accurate pixels, if done correctly.

[There's a great tool by Google that helps generate 9patches here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

(This is assuming you're talking about a standard layout.  If you're doing OGL or something like that, it's a whole different can of worms)

Comment: I am talking about standard layout, but the problem is that won't stretch to fit the size of the device's screen size. If it was stretching but getting distorted images than I would use 9patch. Correct?

Comment: 9patch tiles a bitmap repeatedly, rather than stretching it, so it would be a good fit if you want a consistent border or something like that.

Comment: What kind of image are you talking about?  A background image?  content?

Comment: The problem is not on the background image, but on content images. I am using wrap_content (is it correct? Since I just have image for the screen size 480x800) in all of the ImageView, and I would like that those images would be auto-resized based on device size.

Comment: wrap_content is if you want things to be their actual size.  `match_parent` stretches elements to fit the space available to them.